# What does -1 index of an array in Ruby mean?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Does it mean last referenced index?

Comment: Have any code to demonstrate what context you're talking about? Also, perhaps you should **[read the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html).**

Comment: I have, but thought my question would've been more succinct, and I didn't know it would've been mentioned in the array class.

Comment: It was the first result when Googling "ruby array negative index." https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby%20array%20negative%20index Please search before you ask.

Comment: I searched "ruby array -1". Never thought of searching "negative index".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Negative array indices count backwards from the end. -1 is the last element.

See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D